# Force exerted on Curved Surface

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was studying for some quizzes when I found this question. It goes like this:

> A vertical cylindrical tank of diameter 20 feet and height 30 feet, is full of water. Find the total force normal to the curved surface.

My work:

I cut the cylinder and spread it into a rectangle just to make things easier, because I thought a cylinder filled with water is just the same thing as submerging a rectangle underwater.

I know that the force exerted by liquid on the submerged surface is equal to 
product of density, surface area of object, and depth of centroid of area below the surface. In short, $F = w A \bar y$

So...we got:

F = force exerted by water on the surface

W = density of water = 62.4 pounds per cubic foot

A = area of rectangle = $(2 \pi (10) feet)(30 feet)$ = $600 \pi ft^2$

$\bar y$= midway between the width of rectangle submerged in water = $\frac{30 feet}{2}$ = 15 feet

We can now get the Force:

$$F = w A \bar y$$

$$F = (62.4 \frac{Ib}{ft^3})(600 \pi \space ft^2)(15 \space ft) $$

$$ F = 561600 \pi \space Ib$$

Converting it to tons:

$$561600\pi \space Ib \left( \frac{0.4536 \space kg}{1 \space Ib}  \right)  \left (\frac{1 \space ton}{1 000 \space kg} \right)  = 800 \space tons$$

But book's answer is 882 tons.

Tell me....where did I go wrong?

Comment: Maybe this is better for the physics site?

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor No..I found this question on a Calculus bookXD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One ton is $2000$ lb therefore

$$\frac{561600}{2000}\pi=882.16\text{ tons}$$

Comment: Ah! the correct conversion woul be: $561600\pi \space Ib \left( \frac{0.4536 \space kg}{1 \space Ib}  \right)  \left (\frac{1 \space ton}{907.185 \space kg} \right)  = 882.17 \space tons$